# Is there any way to create multi log file with one configfile.properties?

Tags: python, logging, configparser, configuration-files

In python I wrote the `configfile.properties` file as following for logging:

```
[loggers]=
keys=root

[handlers]=
keys=fileHandler

[formatters]=
keys=myFormatter

[logger_root]=
level=INFO
handlers=fileHandler

[handler_fileHandler]=
class=FileHandler
level=INFO
formatter=myFormatter
args=("/opt/myfile1.log",)

[formatter_myFormatter]=
format=%(process)d-%(levelname)s-%(asctime)s %(name)s->%(funcName)s->%(lineno)-d: %(message)s
```

And i used it in a .py file as following:

```
import logging
import logging.config    
logging.config.fileConfig(fname='configfile.properties', disable_existing_loggers=False)
    logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
```

I call multiple REST API service and then i want to store each APIs log in specific files, I need to create multi log file (`/opt/myfile1.log`, `/opt/myfile2.log`, `/opt/myfile3.log`) with one config file. Is there any way to create these files using that `configfile.properties`?

Comment: definitely, but this depends on how you actually *read* the configfile.  What's the code which actually creates your logging instance?  What's the issue here---creating a logging instance logging to multiple files, or storing multiple values in a config file?  Why exactly do you need these multiple files (might clarify the answer)

Comment: Thanks all. I updated my question that shows how to use config file for logging and clarify my question